# Should a half Jewish man be discouraged from marrying a Jewess?

Tags: am-yisrael-jewish-nation, matrilineal-descent, jewishness

Is there any source in encouraging a man who identifies as Jewish but isn't so Halachically, to marry a Jewish woman and raise a Jewish family?

For instance, a patrilineal Jew although he isn't Jewish, if he is a cultural Jew and wishes to continue his Jewish family's legacy should he still be disuaded from marrying a non-religious Jewish woman? Is there a religious duty or source to have Jewish children?

Note: 
I ask because I am aware that a convert who is patrilineally Jewish has a slightly different status to a regular convert as he has the status of 'זרע ישראל' and is considered “מקרב אחיך" according the Aruch haShulchan in Choshen Mishpat 7:1.

Answer (score 16):

The man isn't Jewish in this case, so he has no obligation whatsoever in marrying a Jewish woman. It is forbidden for the Jewish woman to marry this man because he is not a Jew. If the man truly feels a connection with Judaism he should convert.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of how he considers himself, he is not Jewish. Subsequently, it is not just *not encouraged*, but *forbidden* for him to marry a Jewess.

Comment: Which prohibition is that for him?

Comment: @DoubleAA kosby bas tzur for example (to avoid baal peor issues)

Comment: @Orangesandlemons https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43388

Comment: @Y  e  z nice find, and according to those mefarshim it looks like it wouldn't be forbidden as such. However, it's perhaps worth mentioning that I'm fairly confident that when G-d tells someone 'don't do x' and someone actively encourages someone to _do_ x, they are effectively setting themselves against Hashem and is forbidden _misvarah_ even if not a direct 'mitzvah'.